# Redefining environment trouble

Tags: latex

I'm trying to renew the "enumerate" environment so that there is a bracket instead of a dot after the number. Actually here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[top = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm, bottom = 1.5cm, left = 1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools} % DeclarePairedDelimiter
\usepackage{nomencl}
\let\originalenumerate\enumerate
\renewenvironment{enumerate}{\begin{originalenumerate}[label={$\left.\arabic*\right)$}]}{\end{originalenumerate}\\}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{corollary*}{Corollary}
\begin{document}
\section*{Theorems}
\begin{theorem}
Let
\begin{enumerate}
\item Condition 1,
\item Condition 2,
\item Condition 3,
\end{enumerate}
then assertion.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

This raises a trouble whose solution I can’t google: the last item always moves to the left.

[image]

There is one more nuisance - if I don't write `\\` after `\end{originalenumerate}` there will be no line break.

How can I solve these troubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that you just store the code for the original start of enumerate, but not `\endenumerate`, which means that `\end{originalenumerate}` does not really do anything. Also writing `\\` anywhere outside a tabular environment is nearly always wrong and in your case it causes an error if one would properly store the end of enumerate with `\let\endoriginalenumerate\endenumerate`.

Anyway, much simpler than redefining the enumerate environment, you can use `\setlist{label={$\left.\arabic*\right)$}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[top = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm, bottom = 1.5cm, left = 1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools} % DeclarePairedDelimiter
\usepackage{nomencl}

\setlist{label={$\left.\arabic*\right)$}   

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{corollary*}{Corollary}
\begin{document}
\section*{Theorems}
\begin{theorem}
Let
\begin{enumerate}
\item Condition 1,
\item Condition 2,
\item Condition 3,
\end{enumerate}
then assertion.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```